# How to set the HttpOnly flag to true for xsrf-token cookie in jersey?

Tags: java, cookies, jersey, x-xsrf-token

I'm trying to set the HttpOnly flag of xsrf-token cookie to true in my jersey application.
At the moment I have two cookies, the HttpOnly flag of the jsession id cookie is set to true while the other is set to false.

I have this in my web.xml:

```
  <session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
<cookie-config>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
    <secure>true</secure>
</cookie-config>
<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
```

But the xsrf cookie HttpOnly flag is always false.
How can i change the flag of that cookie?